# Unable to copy text out of MapInfo 12 info tool

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

As the title says, I'm currently unable to copy and paste information out of the info tool box. Is there a way that this can be done normally or do I need to write a new tool/ is there a tool out there currently that allows me do to this?

I'm using MapInfo 12 on a Windows 7 machine (if that helps).

Comment: I think it is a common issue in MapInfo, try waiting a few seconds after selecting an item with the info tool and try again

Comment: The issue is to do with Tables that I (or other users) don't have write access to but are able to read (I realise I should have said that at the start)

Comment: Ah, yes. Unfortunately the Info tool doesn't let you mark and copy text from read-only columns. Could you select the text from the browser window instead (haven't tested if that's possible)

Comment: You can select the text from a browser window, but only by whole rows. eg; I can't just pull the UPRN off a property, I have to copy and paste the whole block of information, which can be quite a lot in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comments on the question, you can avoid copying all the columns from the browser window by running a query using *SQL Select* to hold only the columns that you do want to copy ie just UPRN. A selection made on the base table will also be shown in the browser window of the query table meaning that you should be able to use this approach efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like another solution. A utility that may be able to grab otherwise unselectable text from many program 'messages'. I haven't tried it myself, but it was discussed on this reputable tech site.
www.ghacks.net/2016/03/28/textify-copy-text-that-cannot-be-copied